# Standard deviation of game results about predictions from a rating system

Tags: stochastic-processes, mathematical-statistics, games

I'm very in to Sports analysis and am keen to look at finessing my analysis models that I have worked up  (I don't have a great maths background, I've just done a little bit of reading).

Standard deviation of Game Results about prediction from a Ratings system (in this case least squares regression with a few tweaks) equals the stochastic element in a normal distribution function where:

x = the margin of victory that you are trying to get a % against (e.g. it could be a point spread e.g. % to cover)
the mean = the predicted margin of victory derived in this case from my least squares regression to create power ratings for teams
sigma = standard deviation of error on the difference between the predicted margin of victory and actual margin of victory based on past results.

Based on the above I would treat in Excel terms a win % for team A as:

1-NORMDIST(0.5,mean,sigma,true) - with the mean and sigma having values obviously.

Based on Stern "The Probability of Winning an American Football Game" American Statistician (August 1991) - the sigma value (stochastic element? - sorry this isn't my usual thing) is approximately 13.86. How would you go about refining this for other sports? - e.g. Australian Rules Football. I said this could be done for any sport (and I believe it can within reason unless the results or the sport doesn't lend itself to this type of analysis).

Looking at past AFL results from the end of the season point of view the standard deviations are as follows (have only started looking at these in the last two days):

2009: 31.34 (150+ results)
2010: 33.44 (150+ results
2011: 34.91 (150+ results)
2012: 25.62 (only approximately 70 results so far as it is mid season)

As you feed more data into the model for 2012 it will build up a more accurate picture but looking at past data I'm putting the sigma value for AFL at around 33.5 (above the 25.62 value). Is there anyway of defining a best fit value? Where I don't have a great background in this kind of thing, if someone could give me some gentle nudges in the right direction in terms of where I should be looking or what I could be applying I would be grateful.

I believe this can definitely be applied to other sports as well e.g.:

English Premiership:

2008/2009: 1.45 (Season with over 300+ results)
2009/2010: 1.52
2010/2011: 1.54
2011/2012: 1.64 (but when looking over the last 100 results around the 1.50 mark)

I've also looked at the percentages that this then gives for home wins, away wins and draws and they are virtually identical to the percentages for bookmakers odds (except they work to 105-106% instead of 100% so they have an edge which accounts for the small differences).

NBA:

2008/2009: 11.30 (Season with 1000+ results)
2009/2010: 11.56
2010/2011: 10.88
2011/2012: 11.36

Thanks in advance for any advice,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common in sports to predict outcomes using logistic regression or if you want to predict a continuous response linear regression.
In logistic regression the response Y has 2 values (win or lose in the case of a sporting event outcome) So the outcome is usually coded as 0 for loss and 1 for win.
The model is y=a1 X1 + a2 X2 +a3 X3 +....+ e.  The response y=log(p/1-p)  where p is the unknown probability of success and X1, X2, X2,... are the vsrisble that are used to predict y. In linear regression you have the same form as with logistic regression except that y is the response rather than a function of it. e is the random component or stochastic element.  It is there to express error (sometimes measurement error in determining y).  In these models the error term is assumed to be additive.  Also the Xi are assumed to be determined without error. Using the model and data for the Xis and the corresponding ys the regression parameters a1, a2,a3, ... are estimated (usually by least squares).  Often the error term e is assumed to be normally distributed with me an 0.  They are independent of the Xis and independent of each other. The variability of the error term is defined by the standard deviation sigma which is assumed to be constant (i. e. the same for each sample).  For the normal distribution the mean and standard deviation uniquely determine the distribution.  These models are general and the technique can be applied in any sport.  The covariate and response variables can differ from sport to sport.  It is important to keep the modeling assumptions in mind and if they don't seem to apply alternative approaches may need to be considered.

The American Statistical Association has a section on Statistics in Sports. Hal Stern whose article you cited is a member of that section. He has written substantially on sports. other members Jim Albert and Michael Schell have written books specifically on baseball. You might want to consider joining the association and the section. On the ASA website there is an eGroup for the section where questions like yours are discussed. I am a member but haven't actively done research in it. Many members of the section have though.

Other prominent members that I have not yet mentioned are Carl Morris and Scott Berry.

What is the sample size and do you have bins with fewer than 5 observations? I ask these questions because very small departures from normality can be detect in large samples. Also the chi square test is approximate and doesn't work well when there are bins with fewer than 5 observations. The median seems a lot larger than the mean which would indicate high skewness. But that doesn't show up in the skewness statistic.The standard deviation is large but the standard error is small which indicate a large sample size.

Since the ratio of the standard deviation tio the standard error should be the sqaure root of n, your sample size must be close to 600. I calculated 576 and looking at our data again I see count =567 is probably your sample size and that would make sense. I would like to see a histogram and a Q-Q plot. The conclusion is non-normal but it is not yet clear to me that the departure from normality is large enough to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for the information - it's helpful to get a better understanding (we did this kind of thing at school but there was never a practical application so it was difficult to see where it was relevant). I would say what I am doing is essentially logistic but instead of coding 0 and 1, I am using actual games scores (which does affect the ratings as they are skewed by one-sided results). I am definitely keen to try and get a general approximation for e (if there is such a things as best fit for stochastic elements) and the given the past data you can get access to I think this achievable.

Comment: The American Statistical Association has a section on Statistics in Sports.  Hal Stern whose article you cited is a member of that section.  He has written substantially on sports.  other members Jim Albert and Michael Schell have written books specifically on baseball. You might want to consider joining the association and the section.  On the ASA website there is an eGroup for the section where questions like yours are discussed.  I am a member but haven't actively done research in it.  Many members of the section have though.

Comment: Other prominent members that I have not yet mentioneed are Carl Morris and Scott Berry.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'm keen to improve the models generally (side interest) and I'm just keen to refine the AFL one (hence why I worked up the last three years data to get a clearer idea of the e value as I figured the 2012 one was wrong or there wasn't enough data yet most likely). I know the model is generally solid though as it has gone 11/21 on general bet-able outcomes (so far this weekend - one game remaining) and 6 out of 7 on totals (which these models seem sharp on - 10% return off of my German Ice Hockey model  - or the totals are badly handicapped).

Comment: I went away and looked into the Chi Square test, and carried out a Chi Square test on the error of my prediction against the result:

Comment: DESCRIPTIVE STATISTICS 
Mean 0.00000160
Standard Error 1.395945948
Median 0.393745022
Standard Deviation 33.2399324
Sample Variance 1104.893106
Kurtosis 0.030249713
Skewness 0.081407243
Range 221.2779953
Minimum -104.080249
Maximum 117.1977463
Sum 0.000908841
Count 567
Confidence Level(95.0%) 2.741866796, Chi Squared Statistic = 223.79, df=21 (24 filled bins, 2 parameters), p=0 (so I reject the null hypothesis but I'm not sure what this means). I can provide further information if it helps (e.g. the histogram) but any nudges in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the sample size and do you have bins with fewer than 5 observations?  I ask these questions because very small departures from normality can be detect in large samples. Also the chi square test is approximate and doesn't work well when there are bins with fewer than 5 observations. The median seems a lot larger than the mean which would indicate high skewness.  But that doesn't show up in the skewness statistic.The standard deviation is large but the standard error is small which indicate a large sample size.

Comment: Since the ratio of the standard deviation tio the standard error should be the sqaure root of n, your sample size must be close to 600.  I calculated 576 and looking at our data again I see count =567 is probably your sample size and that would make sense.  I would like to see a histogram and a Q-Q plot.  The conclusion is non-normal but it is not yet clear to me that the departure from normality is large enough to worry about.

Comment: The sample size is 567 - and I do have bins with fewer than 5 observations, I'll try and post the histogram but I don't know if the formatting will work in a comment: Bin Frequency
-120 0
-90 2
-70 5
-50 31
-40 31
-30 38
-25 27
-20 19
-15 24
-10 47
-5 35
0 21
5 35
10 38
15 23
20 34
25 26
30 26
40 43
50 26
70 25
90 8
120 3
More 0 - I don't know what a Q-Q plot is but I will find out and come back with the info. I've done the Chi Squared in Excel and had it verified by someone. I intend to try and do a K-S test on this next. Bin number starts at -120 with 0, -90 with 2, etc.

Comment: Incidentally the sample size of 567 is the last 3 full years of AFL data (in the same way the Stern study went with 3 full years of NFL data) I just wanted to make sure there was enough data in there to make a reasonable study.

Comment: Q-Q stands for quantile vs quantile.  It is like log paper for normal distributions.  Things are scaled so that normally distributed data will fall close to a straight line. It provides an informal graphical check.  I think redefining the bins will help with the validity of the chi square test.

Comment: I tried to figure out what I needed to do for a QQ plot in Excel but I don't think that I could quite figure it out but I think I've managed a normal probability plot. I've posted a jpeg of the plot here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/641/aflnormalprobability.jpg/ - from my very basic understanding of this the fact that it is approximately in a straight line would suggest a normally distributed data set? Providing I'm on the right lines I will redefine the bins and post fresh Chi Squared data.

Comment: I think I have definitely have got this being normally distributed now around the 33.2 mark in terms of standard deviation/the stochastic element. I've added links in to screenshots from an Excel workup I've done on a KS Test which suggests normal distribution and a QQ plot which again suggests normal distribution (I have corrected the link above). http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/7521/aflkstestresult.jpg - is the ks and http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/7367/aflnormalprobability.jpg is what I think is the QQ. If this matches what you were thinking I'm happy to accept an answer.

Comment: sorry I meant to ping you on the above (I hope this makes sense). The nudges you've provided me in the right direction I think have resolved this and I would be happy to accept an answer on that basis.

Comment: @user8812: If writing a comment under an answer or a question, the author of the post (and most recent editor) will *automatically* get a notification (even if you don't address them using @). For example, Michael is going to get pinged in addition to you when this comment gets posted. :)

Comment: @Cardinal thanks for the advice re: pinging - I didn't realise and couldn't figure why when I tried to add at MichaelC it didn't show. From the screenshots above does my logic appear sound that this is normal distributed? (sorry for asking I just have close to no relevant background in this kind of thing and am not 100% sure on this).